# Issue with changing the variable of an sql with php

Tags: php, jquery

I have multiple product category, so base on the page that I click I want to be able to change the `WHERE pc.item_category_id = 3` to `pc.item_category_id = $cat_value`.

**test.php**

```
<div id="get_product" class="form-row">
    // <?php $cat_value = 3; ?> does not work, error in sql
</div>
```

**action.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["getProduct"])){
    $product_query = "SELECT * FROM product_items as pi 
                    INNER JOIN product_category as pc ON pi.item_category = pc.item_category
                    WHERE pc.item_category = 3 // need to be able to change that to a variable like $cat_value
                    ORDER BY pi.product_item_id LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = $conn->query($product_query);
    etc...
    //WHERE pc.item_category = 3 to WHERE pc.item_category = $cat_value does not work
}
```

**test.js**

```
function product(){
    $.ajax({
        url :   "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data    :   {getProduct:1},
        success :   function(data){
            $("#get_product").html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: you know that `test.php` and `action.php` are not on the same page right?

Comment: yeah that why I want to know how to change the variable even if they are not in the same page

Comment: You should probably also look into using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially if all those variables are user inputs.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the `$cat_value` via AJAX to php?

Comment: could you expl to me how to do it please, still a bit new to this whole php/ajax/jquery thing